# set sequence number for group of data

Tags: oracle, ssis

I want to simulate a sequence number for a set of record in SSIS. the challenge is running sequence number start with 1 and increment by 1 for each POLNO,RNWNO,ENDNO,RISKNO combination. I know how to create continuous sequence but I don't know how to depend on it to these for parameter in ssis. my source is Oracle and I am moving data by SSIS to another Oracle database. please help me.

wise 
Example

```
Polno   Ren   End  Risk   ID Number   Seqno
p1          0      0        1        ID01               1
p1          0      0        1        ID02               2
p1          0      0        1        ID03               3
p1          0      0        2        ID04               1
p1          0      0        2        ID05               2
p1          0      0        2        ID06               3
p1          0      1        1        ID01               1
p1          0      1        1        ID02               2
p1          0      1        1        ID03               3
p1          0      1        2        ID04               1
p1          0      1        2        ID05               2
p1          0      1        2        ID06               3
```

Comment: How would you create a continuous sequence? If you're thinking of the analytic function `row_number()` to do that, then it's easy to amend it to run across different groups (hint, "partitions")...

Comment: @Boneist: that is nice idea but I want to have it as second options

Comment: what do you mean by "second options"?

Comment: @Boneist: means as PlanB

Answer (score 1):

An Oracle solution is to use the `ROW_NUMBER` analytic function:

```
SELECT t.*,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
         PARTITION BY POLNO,RNWNO,ENDNO,RISKNO ORDER BY IDNumber
       ) AS SeqNo
FROM   your_table t;
```

Comment: Tq for your trick but may I know do you have any solution by using SSIS components?

Comment: Create the above query as a view and then use that in SSIS?